# Tabulator: reformat cell on 'cellEdited' event

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am new at using Tabulator.js but I am willing to learn and use it deeply. I was indeed looking for a good tableGenerator library for a main project. So far, it seems to be pretty nice.
I am currently using a CND link for version 5.0.7.

Now here is my problem: I try to format cell with a `background-color` depending on the cell value (the cell name is status and the value can be either `true` or `false`). It works at the creation of the table. But it doesn't work if I change the cell value afterwards.

I created a method called `statusFormatter`:

```js
statusFormatter: (cell) => {

        if (cell.getValue() == true) {
            cell.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "#A6A6DF";
        }

        return cell.getValue();
},
```

I call this method on the `cellEdited` event:

```js
mainTable.on("cellEdited", function (cell) {
    clientTabulator.statusFormatter(cell);
});
```

I suppose there is something wrong with the return in the method. But I don't know what to return when it is the style that I need.

Hope someone can help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `statusFormatter` function as

```
statusFormatter: function (cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
  
  let position = cell.getRow().getPosition();

  // switch row even and  odd color
  let backgroundColor = cell.getValue() ? "#A6A6DF" : position % 2 ? "#efefef" : "#fff";
  cell.getElement().style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;

  return cell.getValue();

}
```

Comment: Thank you Double H ! Hope you had a nice Christmas time:)  I now understand my mistake, I was only returning a background color for some of cells as I should have returned a background-color for all the cells of the column. I used your short code and I still have a little problem (not my initial problem though): the odd and even rows are not well identified as I sort the table using the initialSort property. It looks like the getPosition function returns the position of the row before sorting datas.